# Could not open authorized keys Permission denied when trying to connect via SFTP

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, chroot-jail

I'm trying to create a chrooted SFTP user using public key authentication, on a Centos 7 server running Plesk Obsidian.

I've set it all up, but when I try to connect via SFTP I get "FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused".

When I try connecting using a debug port...

```
$ `which sshd` -p 123 -Dddd
```

...I get the following error:

```
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 10026/1010 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
```

I've searched and searched looked at loads of tutorials and I just can't work out what is preventing access to `authorized_keys`.

My setup is as follows:

I added a user account, `testuser`, to group `sftponly`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep testuser

testuser:x:10026:1010::/home/testuser/chroot/httpdocs:/bin/false
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/group | grep sftponly

sftponly:x:1010:
```

I set up the folder structure as follows:

```
$ ls /home -la | grep testuser

drwx------.  4 root      root      4096 Feb 10 15:52 testuser
```

```
$ ls /home/testuser -la

drwx------. 4 root root     4096 Feb 10 15:52 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root     4096 Feb  9 15:22 ..
drwxr-x--x. 3 root sftponly 4096 Feb 10 15:52 chroot
drwx------. 2 root sftponly 4096 Feb  9 15:24 .ssh
```

```
$ ls /home/testuser/chroot -la

drwxr-x--x.  3 root     sftponly  4096 Feb 10 15:52 .
drwx------.  4 root     root      4096 Feb 10 15:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 30 testuser psaserv  32768 Feb  9 14:13 httpdocs
```

```
$ ls /home/testuser/.ssh -la

drwx------. 2 root     sftponly 4096 Feb  9 15:24 .
drwx------. 4 root     root     4096 Feb 10 15:52 ..
-rwx------. 1 testuser sftponly  390 Feb  9 15:24 authorized_keys
```

I know authorized keys is in a valid format as I copied it from an SSH user so I can use the same key whilst testing:

```
$ cat /home/testuser/.ssh/authorized_keys

ssh-rsa AAA...redacted my_comment
```

My sshd_config contains this block for the sftponly group:

```
Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /home/%u/chroot
        AuthorizedKeysFile /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        PermitTunnel no
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
```

sshd_config also includes the following flags:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And SELinux is set to permissive mode:

```
$ cat /etc/selinux/config

# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Plus I've tried running restorecon as has been suggested in lots of threads but to no avail:

```
$ restorecon -FRv /home/testuser/.ssh
```

Here's a dump of my system info if it's helpful:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

18.0.33.0
Plesk Obsidian 18.0
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

I'm really stumped on this one! I've exhausted everything I can think of! Any insight would be very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just answered my own question lol. Btw it is possible to store the keys outside of the chroot as chroot is actioned only after the login step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! Clearly I just had to write it all out on here so that I could figure it out ‍♂️

For those searching, `testuser` did not have access to `authorized_keys` as the `/home/testuser` folder required 750 permissions, ie read and execute under the `sftponly` group.

PHEW